# LibreOffice(4.4.3) Headless PDF Conversion issue for some MSWords documents

Tags: java, pdf, libreoffice, headless, document-conversion

I am able to convert most of the word documents(doc & docx) to PDF on windows.

```
"soffice.exe" --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir "C:\Ok"  "C:\Ok\Test_Original.doc"
```

But a few documents are not getting converted and I see the following intermediate file generated

```
.~lock.Test_Original.pdf#
```

No errors or warnings.Not sure how I can get around this issue. Any suggestions or alternate solutions to LibreOffice. I intend to convert docs to pdf on the server.

Comment: Do you get anything on stdout/stderr?

Comment: no, It exits normally.